# giving an XML child and automatic id with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

Does anybody know how to give a child in XML and automatic ID using jQuery?

so that it can be used to identify just that child

for instance if I have an xml like this

```
<parent>

   <child title="test"/>
   <child title="test"/>

</parent>
```

and then in the HTML it will be compiled to look like this

```
<p id=1>test</p>
<p id=2>test</p>
```

this is as far as I got with the jquery

```
function Template(xml) {

    $(xml).find('parent').each(function () {
        var body = $('body').addClass('nobg');

         $(xml).find('child').each(function() {

            var count = 1;

            if ($(this).attr('title') > '') {
               var title = $('<p></p>').appendTo(body);
               headline.attr('id'), (count++));
            }
       })
   })
}
```

as you can see it does not count it just puts an id of 1 in field

Comment: Please post your attempt if any

Comment: put it up as requested

Comment: You should move the declaration of count one block up, otherwise it gets reinitialized for each item.

Comment: `as you can see it does not count it just puts an id of 1 in field`. Where can this be seen?

Comment: Thanks Kris you are my saviour and now I will go and bang my head on my desk for not seeing that for the last 3 hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

I moved the declaration of `count` and added the titleText to the new paragraph.

```
function Template(xml) {
    var count = 1;
    $(xml).find('parent').each(function () {
        var body = $('body').addClass('nobg');

         $(xml).find('child').each(function() {
            var titleText = $(this).attr('title');
            if (titleText.length > 0) {
                var title = $('<p></p>').appendTo(body);
                title.append(titleText);
                headline.attr('id', (count++));
            }
       })
   })
}
```

**Edit**: fixed issues identified by A Wolff

Comment: If more than one parent, this would give duplicate IDs and BTW there is syntax error here: `headline.attr('id'), (count++));`

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `count` is just the single child you are processing. Move it to a higher scope:

```
$(xml).find('parent').each(function () {
    var body = $('body').addClass('nobg');

    var count = 1;

     $(xml).find('child').each(function() {

        if ($(this).attr('title') > '') {
           var title = $('<p></p>').appendTo(body);
           headline.attr('id'), (count++));
        }
    })
})
```

Also, to be on the safe side, I would replace `count++` with `++count` as you need it to increment before it is used. This is pure readability, though, in your case.

Comment: If more than one parent, this would give duplicate IDs and BTW there is syntax error here: `headline.attr('id'), (count++));`

Answer (score 0):

use prefix ++count. it first increments

```
function Template(xml) {

    $(xml).find('parent').each(function () {
        var body = $('body').addClass('nobg');

         $(xml).find('child').each(function() {

            var count = 1;

            if ($(this).attr('title') > '') {
               var title = $('<p></p>').appendTo(body);
               headline.attr('id'), (++count));
            }
       })
   })
}
```